# Why are PCIe Config Writes non-posted?

Tags: pcie, pci

In PCIe, why are config writes non-posted?  Why can't they be like mem_wr which are posted?

Comment: What PCIe device are you referring to? And where are you getting this information from?

Comment: Not reference to any specific device.  Fundamentally (per the PCIe spec) configuration writes are non-posted (where a completion status is expected).  Memory space writes are posted (fire and forget, no completion  response is sent back).

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely for reliability and transaction ordering purposes.  The host can simply wait for a reply to know that the write transaction has gone through successfully, unlike posted writes which don't have any feedback.  This can be very important when configuring hardware registers as things have to happen in a very specific order.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Yes, the completion for the cfgwr provides a guarantee. Like you said "most likely".  I can't see what would break had it been a posted. 
 In terms of ordering, making it a posted would be even stronger since no other transaction can pass it.  So not sure how the argument on ordering holds.

Comment: @user7656686 you are assuming that the device always receives and reacts properly and timely

Comment: @PlasmaHH I am not sure what you meant.  Can you explain if possible?